# Define variable and check number range

Tags: python, numbers, range

This is the code but instead of input. I need to call a variable "num_input". The "num_input" already has the question that needs input back from the user.

How can I do that?

```
while True:
  try:
    **input** = int(raw_input('Check range 111-119 >>> '))
    if input in range(1,10):
      break
    else:
      print 'Not in range. Try again'
  except:
    print ("That's not a number")
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I got input from the user, stored that new value in a variable called "num_check", and now I want to do a loop that see if the user entered value in within the given range.

Comment: In that case, please edit your question accordingly — or risk having it closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    try:
        value = int(raw_input('Check range 111-119 >>> '))
        if value >= 111 and value < 119:
            break
        else:
            print 'Not in range, try again'
    except ValueError:
        print 'That is not a number'
```

Testing

> Check range 111-119 >>> word
>   That is not a number
>   Check range 111-119 >>> 15
>   Not in range, try again
>   Check range 111-119 >>> 116